# Node.js changing system date and impact on moment.js

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to change the current date on Node.js? Instead of current date, I would like to set the current date 28th October 2018.

My application heavily rely on Moment.js so, I need to ensure Moment.js recognises the changed date.

Comment: Change date in your machine

Comment: @ma_dev_15 How about using something like mockdate NPM package? -->  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate